# Importing Vue Grid Layout in Shopware Module leads to Resolve Error

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to use the [Vue Grid Layout](https://jbaysolutions.github.io/vue-grid-layout) library in my module. I followed the installation process mentioned in the [Shopware guide](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/v/6.4/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/using-npm-dependencies) to install the NPM package (performed in the administration). However, when I attempt to import Vue Grid Layout using the statement `import VueGridLayout from '@vue-grid-layout';`, I encounter the following error:

```
resolve '@vue-grid-layout' in '/var/www/html/custom/plugins/ShopwareWidgets/src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/m28-widgetFactory/page/m28-widgetFactory-Dashboard'
Parsed request is a module
Using description file: /var/www/html/package.json (relative path: ./custom/plugins/ShopwareWidgets/src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/m28-widgetFactory/page/m28-widgetFactory-Dashboard)
Aliased with mapping '@vue-grid-layout': '/var/www/html/custom/plugins/ShopwareWidgets/src/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/vue-grid-layout' to '/var/www/html/custom/plugins/ShopwareWidgets/src/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/vue-grid-layout'
```

You can find the full error trace [here](https://goonlinetools.com/online-clipboard/#1098).

Additionally, when I try to use the browser-ready bundle of Vue Grid Layout, my module doesn't compile at all. I don't receive any error messages or logs to debug the issue.

Could someone please help me resolve this import error and provide guidance on successfully using Vue Grid Layout in my Shopware module?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Given your `webpack.config.js` looks something like this:

```js
const { join, resolve } = require('path'); 
module.exports = () => { 
    return { 
        resolve: { 
           alias: { 
               '@vue-grid-layout': resolve( 
                    join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'vue-grid-layout') 
               ) 
           } 
       } 
   }; 
}
```

Confirm that you installed the package in the right directory. In this case the directory should be located at

```
<plugin root>/src/Resources/app/storefront/node_modules/vue-grid-layout
```

So you should've executed `npm install vue-grid-layout` in the `storefront` directory and that's where the resulting `package.json` should be at.

Comment: I've spent hours struggling with vue grid layout, tried this multiple times, reinstalled Shopware, and rebuilding the plugin. I even tried to redo the entire plugin 4 times. The error "'Can't resolve 'vue' in ...' keeps haunting me. Is Shopware incompatible with vue grid layout? Desperate for a solution. Please help!